# Groovy extract list of XML nodes in another file

Tags: groovy

I have xml file which contains thousands of xml nodes. In my groovy code I want to extract N of them and push into another file. How I can do this with groovy?
Some sample listing:

```groovy
def ibr = new File('/Users/alex/Downloads/temp.xml');
def ibrParser = new XmlParser().parseText(ibr.getText());


def groups = [];
int current = 0;

ibrParser.each { group ->
    if (current <= 100) {
        groups<<group
    }
    current++
}
//how to store groups as xml into another file?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code helped me:

```groovy
int current = 0;

def nodeToSerialize;

ibrParser.each { renewalQuote ->
    if (current <= 100) {
        if (nodeToSerialize == null) {
            nodeToSerialize = renewalQuote;
        } else {
            nodeToSerialize.append(renewalQuote)
        }
    }
    current++
}


XmlUtil.serialize(nodeToSerialize, new FileOutputStream("/Users/alex/Downloads/100Cases.xml"))
```